# How to use keyword `where` for multiple generic types?

Tags: c#

I have this interface:

```
interface ILooperable<in TASK_TYPE, in CALLBACK_TYPE>
```

I would like to set the first parameter to implement `foo` and second parameter to `boo`, something like this:

```
interface ILooperable<in TASK_TYPE, in CALLBACK_TYPE> where TASK_TYPE: foo, CALLBACK_TYPE : boo
```

But it doesn't work,

It says:

> Syntax error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should repeat the `where` keyword:

```cs
interface ILooperable<in TASK_TYPE, in CALLBACK_TYPE>
where TASK_TYPE: foo
where CALLBACK_TYPE : boo { }
```

You can read more about its usage on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint).